# Splitting Mesh or creating model exploding effect

Tags: language-agnostic

Is there anyway we can split mesh (exploding mesh effect) in java? Please give me code that is doing this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this example in XNA, it uses a shader to achieve the effect you are looking for:
http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/shatter

[image: Shatter Effect]

Perhaps you can map the technique to something similar in Java

Comment: I had already seen this code.